# Interfacing a linux device driver with dummy PCI device

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, emulation, pci-e

I have a user space program that simulates a PCI device. I have downloaded the nvme linux device driver that interacts with the PCI device using the NVMe standard. I have to verify that my userspace program is compatible with the standard.

The nvme.c(the linux device driver) contains the nvme_probe() function that would be called when the device is plugged in. Since I do not have the device so I think I will incorporate the probe functionality in nvme_init() function.

Now I have studied quite a lot on the internet to understand how to emulate a PCI device, posts such as 
    [Installing PCI driver without connection to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714555/installing-linux-pci-driver-without-connecting-the-device),
[emulating a PCI device on linux](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-emulate-a-pci-device-in-linux-901554/)
I do not get the idea how to return the populated struct pci_dev to the  function call in the `nvme_probe()` of`pci_set_drvdata(pdev, dev);`

And if you could suggest a tutorial, on how to manually populate the pci_dev struct with dummy device configuration and memory address of the userspace program function pointers to emulate interaction with the nvme driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to fake such thing with standard linux kernel.

Because in module_init() you are telling the kernel's **PCI SUBSYSTEM** to load the operation handlers (a.k.a - callbacks through function pointers) when a certain device is present in the system (via id_table).

so whenever you insmod your module, kernel's **PCI SUBSYTEM** then knows to load your driver whenever a device of matching vid/pid is plugged into the PCIe slot. The operation is like below -

- Tell kernel to load {my_driver.ko} when this {vid/pid} pci device is
  found in module_init or _init
- After kernel knew, whenever a matching {vid/pid} device is connected to the system, it will call the **.probe** function callback of {my_driver.ko}
- You may init the device (for real-device) or just return true to tell kernel that  has correctly initialized the device.
  You can also register new driver type from this probe function (for
  read/write).

I am not sure about any magic VID/PID number which causes the **PCI SUBSYTEM** to always load the driver.

But you can actually load the PCI driver by using an actual PCI device.

Just remove appropriate driver for a real-PCI device. and use it's VID & PID as your driver's VID PID. Then the **PCI SUBSYTEM** will load your driver & you can also test your driver to simulate PCI device afterwards.

Hope this helps,

regards.

Comment: Thanks for explaining... It does clear a lot of things. Now I am thinking that I will remove all calls to the PCI subsystem. The nvme driver uses queues to communicate with the PCI device. I am thinking about copying the queue data to user space from where it will trigger the simulation code. Please comment.. And do send me a tutorial on communication of kernel modules with user space programs.

Comment: You can do that to test your program, (if you want to interact with driver only). I don't have any experience on nvme driver, but generally all driver will follow the pattern below - 


[nvme-driver]<---loads--[pci-driver]<--loads--[pci-bus-driver]<----notify-system---[device]. Arrow denotes the loading order. So, If you are enabling a fs driver, I think you have to short-circuit (kind of loopback) the read/write function used in nvme-driver. If you want to just grab data from the driver, you can use netlink. I am not sure which path you want to use. hope this helps

Comment: Does this answer still stand? Any changes on this with newer kernels? Are there any options to emulate a PCIe device without HW?